# Pymongo: Bulk update with $setOnInsert error

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I am trying to do bulk updates, while at the same time retaining the state of a specific field.
In my code I am either creating a document, or add to the list 'stuff'.

```
#init bulk
data = [...]
bulkop = col.initialize_ordered_bulk_op()
for d in data:
   bulkop.find({'thing':d}).upsert().update({'$setOnInsert':{'status':0},'$push':{'stuff':'something'},'$inc': { 'seq': 1 }})
bulkop.execute()
```

However, I am getting an error when I try this.
Error: pymongo.errors.BulkWriteError: batch op errors occurred

It works fine without the $setOnInsert':{'status':0} addition, but I need this to make sure that the state var is not getting updated.

Comment: Solution: After updating my version of mongodb it started working.

Answer (score -1):

I think you are using pymongo 3.x, the above code works on pymongo 2.x. Try this...

```
from pymongo import MongoClient, UpdateMany
client = MongoClient(< connection string >)
db = client[test_db]
col = db[test]
docs = [doc_1,doc_2,doc_3,....,doc_n]

requests = [UpdateMany({ },{'$setOnInsert':{'status':0},"$set":{"$push":docs}}, upsert = True)]
result = col.bulk_write(requests)
print(result.inserted_count)
```

Here empty { } means updating all the records.

Hope this helps...